# Descent datum for a module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

Below is a definition of a descent datum on stacks project:
[image]

It then says that if $N = B \otimes_AM$ for some $A$-module $M$, then it has a canonical descent datum given by the map
$$N \otimes_AB \to B \otimes_AN'$$
$$b_0 \otimes m \otimes b_1 \mapsto b_0 \otimes b_1 \otimes m$$
Why are modules of the form $B \otimes_AM$ special? Don't you always have a descent datum $n \otimes b \mapsto b \otimes n$? for a $B$-module $N$?

Comment: $b\mapsto n$? How does that work?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that's a typo.. I've fixed it.

Comment: I'm sure this descent thing is meant to characterise the $B$-modules that can be tensored up from $A$-modules. I presume $A$ and $B$ are commutative? I don't see what $\phi_{02}$ is in the original diagram though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that your map $\phi:n\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}\ot b\mapsto b\ot n$ is a $B\ot_A B$-module homomorphism.
$$\phi((b_1\ot b_2)(n\ot b))=\phi(b_1n\ot b_2b)=
b_2b\ot b_1 n$$
but
$$(b_1\ot b_2)\phi(n\ot b)=(b_1\ot b_2)(b\ot n)=b_1b\ot b_2n.$$
Those look different to me.

Comment: Aren't they both equal to $(b_1 \otimes b_2)(b \otimes n)$?

Comment: @AaronJohnson No, that's just the second one.